# Adding more than 3 options in C# MessageDialog

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I want to add 4 options in a MessageDialog in C# Windows Store App. I can add 3 options like this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn308255.aspx

But when I am going to app 4th option it throws exception

```
"The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000B)"
```

Is it not possible to add more than 3 options?

Comment: As a side comment: `MessageDialog` is a `MessageBox` descendant which exist from stone-age of windows. And it was always *enough* to have up to 3 options (buttons): Ok, OkCancel, YesNoCancel, RetryAbortCancel, etc. If you need something more complicated, then sure, design and display own modal dialog. Similar concept should be used with windows phone/store/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The message dialog has a command bar that can support up to **three commands**. 
If you don't specify any commands, then a default command is added to **close** the dialog.
if you want to add more option try to override **MessageDialog class**.

Comment: Please be wary: On Windows Phone it only supports 2!